# Cordova android manifest specifying sdks to use

Tags: android, cordova

I have an android app that i want to compile. The current manifest looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.apache.cordova" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
</manifest>
```

I want my app to be as compatible in newer and older android smartphones.The goal is to be compatible with as many devices out there as possible.

If i edited my uses-sdk section like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5.0"
          android:targetSdkVersion="8.1"
          android:maxSdkVersion="8.1" />
```

Will i be saying that my app can run from all devices from 5.0 to 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the API levels instead:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="27"
    android:maxSdkVersion="27" />
```

the [documentation](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) features a handy chart.

**edit**: for a `Cordova` project, these should rather be specified in the root project:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="27" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="27" />
```

Comment: This will support all devices from api 21 to 27 right? Will this make the apk so big?

Comment: @Gandalf nope; it only targets API level `27`; but some backwards-compatible code is required. for example: API level `21` & `22` don't know of any run-time permissions yet. the `build.gradle` most likely would also need to reflect these API levels, because Gradle does not care about the values in the `Manifest.xml` (unless `Cordova` picks them up from there).

Comment: Okay, i dont completely get it. What do i have to do to make a single apk that can run on android version 5.1 to version 8.1 , here are the shares of each version in the ecosystem https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/

Comment: @Gandalf updated my answer, because `Cordova` generates the `Manifest.xml`... the demand for backwards-compatible code affects the plugins written in `Java` only (eg. when using custom plugins). the biggest differences in behavior are in between API levels `22` and `23` and meanwhile in between `25` and `26`. eg. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't have any java plugins or any plugin installed. So, the solution would be having apps for different android versions?.

Comment: @Gandalf then it's nothing to worry about; the available plugins generally consider the differences. still suggested to test with elder/newer devices or emulator images.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance and time.